# Android studio dolphin debugger stuck in collecting data

Tags: android, android-studio

Everything was fine with debugger until I updated studio.
Any ideas how to fix that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRyzQ.png)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue :-\